# Allow invalid path lynx

Tags: web, lynx

I have installed lynx using brew on macOS.  It runs decently after me enabling all cookies http://www.pc-freak.net/blog/how-to-permanently-enable-cookies-in-lynx-text-browser-disable-accept-cookies-prompt-in-lynx-console-browser/

Is there a way to get it to feasible to automatically say yes to "Accept invalid cookie path=/complete/search as a prefix of '/'?"

It asks me on most web pages I visit.  Under the options page it is called "Invalid-cookie prompting."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

invoking lynx as

`lynx -cookies -accept_all_cookies`

seems to do the trick; I have seem some suggestions elsewhere to alias lynx= same...

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to configure it to ignore the problem with specific domains: [**`COOKIE_ACCEPT_DOMAINS`**](https://lynx.invisible-island.net/release/lynx_help/body.html#COOKIE_ACCEPT_DOMAINS).

In a followup comment, mention was made of

```
Invalid-Cookie Prompting
```

That is normally *not* saved to the **`~/.lynxrc`**, as indicated by the **`(!)`** after the name.  You can configure `lynx` to save (and read) the value by adding

```
ENABLE_LYNXRC:FORCE_COOKIE_PROMPT:ON
```

to the **`lynx.cfg`** file.

Comment: Isn't that a comma separated list of domains instead of a universal accept

Comment: yes - I said "specific".

Comment: There is an option for this under the options page that works but I don't know where the option is stored

Comment: I tried this option also it doesn't work

Comment: That actually suppresses prompts for more than the issue you mentioned.  But "doesn't work" can cover a lot more territory.

Comment: For that option it doesn't work for disabling the invalid cookie prompt.  I actually tried that setting and should have posted a comment about it before you mentioned it.  Oh well.